# Why does my wallet size increase over time?

Tags: backup, wallet.dat, keypool

Why does the size of the output of

`bitcoin-cli`[`backupwallet`](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#backupwallet)

or, equivalently, `wallet.dat`

increase over time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current `wallet.dat` file increases because you add new keys when you refill your keypool (get new addresses) or if you receive or send transactions. Mind that every wallet-relevant transaction is stored (together with some metadata) in your wallet.dat.